# How to add scrollbar to every window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code, I'm developing based on a backbone here on stackoverflow. I understand it, but I'm having problems to add a scrollbar. In page 1, after i put the number and press "ok" I generate a certain number of entries. If the number is too big I can't fill in all of them, therefore the need of a scrollbar. I tried different solutions, but none of them worked. I never used a scrollbar before, can someone help me out? Thanks in advance

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import Scrollbar, font as tkfont
from typing_extensions import IntVar  # python 3
from Classi_Utenti import * 

class SampleApp(tk.Tk, FinanziatoreSemplice):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.labels_finanziatori = {
        'principale': [],
        'capitale_investito': [], 
        'tasso': [], 
        'tempo': []
        }

        self.dict_finanziatori = {
        'numero': [],
        'capitale_investito': [], 
        'tasso': [], 
        'tempo': [],
        }

        self.Finanziatori_Semplici = []
        
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
  
        for F in (StartPage, FinanziatoriSemplici):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            
        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
        # notify frame that it is raised via virtual event
        #frame.event_generate("<<Raised>>")
    
    def back_frame(self, page_name, old_frame):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        old_frame = self.frames[old_frame]
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
        for widgets in old_frame.winfo_children():
            widgets.destroy()
        # notify frame that it is raised via virtual event
        #frame.event_generate("<<back>>")

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Benvenuti nel framework di configurazione", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text='Inizia la configurazione', command=lambda: controller.show_frame("FinanziatoriSemplici"))
        button1.pack()

class FinanziatoriSemplici(tk.Frame, FinanziatoreSemplice):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.numero_utenti=tk.IntVar()
        self.Finanziatori_Semplici = [] 

        self.labels_finanziatori = {
            'principale': [],
            'capitale_investito': [], 
            'tasso': [], 
            'tempo': []
            }

        self.dict_finanziatori = {
            'numero': [],
            'capitale_investito': [], 
            'tasso': [], 
            'tempo': [],
            }
        tk.Label(self, text="Configurare I Finanziatori", font=controller.title_font).grid(row=0, column = 0)
        tk.Label(self, text="Inserire il numero di utenti da configurare").grid(row=1, column = 0)
        self.entry_utenti = tk.Entry(self, text="Inserire numero Utenti", textvariable = self.numero_utenti)
        self.entry_utenti.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.btn_utenti = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command= lambda: InizializzaUtenti(self.entry_utenti.get()))
        self.btn_utenti.grid(row=1, column=2)

        def InizializzaUtenti(num):    
            self.numero_utenti = int(num)
            k=3

            for i in range(0, self.numero_utenti):
                #MAIN label del finanziatore
                self.labels_finanziatori['principale'].append(tk.Label(self, text="Dati finanziatore numero "+str(i+1) +":\n"))
                self.labels_finanziatori['principale'][i].grid(row=i*k+3, column = 0)
                k = k+1
                #Label capitale investito
                self.labels_finanziatori['capitale_investito'].append(tk.Label(self, text="Dati sul capitale investito del finanziatore "+str(i+1)))
                self.labels_finanziatori['capitale_investito'][i].grid(row=i*k+4, column = 0, sticky= "W")
                #Entry widget capitale investito
                self.dict_finanziatori['capitale_investito'].append(tk.Entry(self, text = "Inserire il Capitale investito dal finanziatore "+str(i+1)))
                self.dict_finanziatori['capitale_investito'][i].grid(row=i*k+4, column = 1)
                k= k+1
                #Label Tasso di interesse
                self.labels_finanziatori['tasso'].append(tk.Label(self, text="Dati sul tasso di interesse del finanziatore "+str(i+1)))
                self.labels_finanziatori['tasso'][i].grid(row=i*k+5, column = 0,sticky= "W")
                #Entry widget tasso
                self.dict_finanziatori['tasso'].append(tk.Entry(self, text = "Inserire il tasso di interesse"))
                self.dict_finanziatori['tasso'][i].grid(row=i*k+5, column = 1)
                k= k+1
                ############################## N.B. L'ultima label ha pady
                #Label Tempo di ritorno 
                self.labels_finanziatori['tempo'].append(tk.Label(self, text="Inserire il tempo di ritorno per l'investimento per il finanziatore "+str(i+1), anchor='w'))
                self.labels_finanziatori['tempo'][i].grid(row=i*k+6, column = 0, pady=(0, 10), sticky= "W")
                #Entry widget tempo
                self.dict_finanziatori['tempo'].append(tk.Entry(self, text = "Inserire il tempo di ritorno per l'investimento"))
                self.dict_finanziatori['tempo'][i].grid(row=i*k+6, column = 1, pady=(0, 10))
                k= k+1

                tk.Button(self, text="Valida", command = lambda: ValidaFinanziatore(self.dict_finanziatori['capitale_investito'][i])).grid(row=i*k+6, column = 2, pady=(0, 10))
                #Crea bottone per ogni finanziatore per inizializzarlo dove viene verificato anche l'input
                #self.Finanziatori_Semplici.append(FinanziatoreSemplice(float(x), float(self.dict_finanziatori['tasso'][i].get()), float(self.dict_finanziatori['tempo'][i].get()), int(i)))
            

            def ValidaFinanziatore(capitale):
                return
               
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.geometry("900x900")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please make a minimal working example of your problem?

Comment: if you don't want to struggle with scrollbars https://ttkwidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ttkwidgets/ttkwidgets.frames.html after installing import = `import ttkwidgets.frames`

Comment: the code is fully working. I just can't figure out how to add a scrollbar for the various pages... Particularly when I call "FinanziatoriSemplici" and insert the number i want, if the number is too big I can't see all the entries...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/7432